# How to add custom button in R Shiny datatable?

Tags: r, user-interface, button, shiny, dt

There is an option to add a custom button on datatables.net site. How it can be coded in R Shiny app? A basic R code example for one button and observer will be great to see.

Here is JS code from https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/custom.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'My button',
                action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                    alert( 'Button activated' );
                }
            }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to use Javascript, except for the action. You can do:

```
library(DT)
datatable(iris,
          extensions = 'Buttons',
          options = list(
            dom = 'Bfrtip',
            buttons = list(
              "copy",
              list(
                extend = "collection",
                text = 'test',
                action = DT::JS("function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                                    alert( 'Button activated' );
                                }")
              )
            )
          )
)
```

To pass something from Javascript to the shiny server, use `Shiny.setInputValue`:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- basicPage(
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$dtable <- renderDT(
    datatable(iris,
              extensions = 'Buttons',
              options = list(
                dom = 'Bfrtip',
                buttons = list(
                  "copy",
                  list(
                    extend = "collection",
                    text = 'test',
                    action = DT::JS("function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                                      Shiny.setInputValue('test', true, {priority: 'event'});
                                   }")
                  )
                )
              )
    )
  )

  observeEvent(input$test, {
      print("hello")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip! The button "test" appears in the right place without 'action'. But when I added action = DT::JS("function ( e, dt, node, config ) {Shiny.setInputValue('test', true, priority: 'event');}") - nothing shows in the window. Where can be the trick?

Comment: @andrii What do you mean by the "window" ? You want to show an alert ? `Shiny.setInputValue` is to pass a variable to the shiny server. If you want only an alert, remove that and replace with `alert(...)`.

Comment: I mean that dashboard was not appeared with the embedded button "test" - empty blank screen - when I added 'action'

Comment: I used this code example used to add "download all data" button https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/267
thx

Comment: Nice! I used this for my submit / remove selection found in this question also answered by Stephane: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55550126/format-a-vector-of-rows-in-italic-and-red-font-in-r-dt-datatable/55572811#55572811

Comment: If I remove "copy" from the list(), I hope you get only the new button but unfortunately my code breaks. Any suggestions what I should do if I only want to have the custom button?