# R shiny : how can I include "export to LaTeX" button in a datatable?

Tags: r, shiny, latex

I have a Shiny app with a datatable. I would like to implement a button at the top of this datatable (but below its title) so that, when I click on it, the LaTeX code necessary to build this table is copied to clipboard.

Basically, this button would work the same way that the "copy" or "csv" buttons (see [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html) part 2) but with LaTeX code.

Here's a reproducible example :

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(data.table)
library(stargazer)
library(clipr)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "test with mtcars", titleWidth = 1000),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectizeInput("var.cor", label = "Correlation",
                   choices = names(mtcars),
                   selected = c("mpg", "cyl"), 
                   multiple = TRUE)
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("test with mtcars",
               br(),
               box(dataTableOutput("cor"),
                   width = NULL),
               actionButton("copy.latex", label = "Copy to LaTeX")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  var.selected <- reactive({
    out <- input$var.cor
    out
  })

  user.selection <- reactive({
    mtcars <- mtcars[, var.selected()]
  })

  output$cor <- renderDataTable({
    dtable <- user.selection()
    tmp <- datatable(cor(dtable), 
                     extensions = 'Buttons',
                     options = list(
                       dom = 'Bfrtip',
                       buttons = list(
                         "copy",
                         list(
                           extend = "collection",
                           text = 'test',
                           action = DT::JS("function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                                      Shiny.setInputValue('test', true, {priority: 'event'});
                                   }")
                         )
                       )
                     )
    )
    observeEvent(input$test, {
      write_clip(stargazer(tmp), 
                 object_type = "auto")  
    })
    tmp
  }) 

  observeEvent(input$copy.latex, {
    write_clip(stargazer(input$cor), 
               object_type = "character")
  })


}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I tested two things in this code :

- firstly, I inspired from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53600956/how-to-add-custom-button-in-r-shiny-datatable). This is the code of `observeEvent` nested in `renderDataTable`. However, either the text in the clipboard is `% Error: Unrecognized object type`, either I have an error : `Error in : Clipboard on X11 requires that the DISPLAY envvar be configured.`
- secondly, I created a button outside the datatable but it doesn't work because I have `Error in : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Does somebody know how to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To copy the dataframe to clipboard in server:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)
table <- iris[1:10,]

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  actionButton("latex","Copy Latex to Clipboard"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- DT::renderDT(table)

  observeEvent(input$latex,{
    writeClipboard(paste0(capture.output(xtable(table))[-c(1:2)],collapse = "\n"))
    shinyjs::alert("table copied to latex")
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I won't recommend you to do it using DT's button. In order to do it using DT, there are at least 3 steps:

1. read entire table in the UI of datatable by writing Javascript in `action`, use `Shiny.setInputValue` to send the value from UI to server.
2. use R to parse the list(json) into data frame.
3. convert the data frame to latex string.

It's much easier to just do the conversion using the source data for datatable.

Comment: this works fine but that means the LaTeX code generated cannot be reactive, right ?

Comment: It is also interactive in the example I provided as long as you change the source data, but achieving it in JS is hard. You need to write your own function in JS to convert json to Latex code. Otherwise, you need to do the several steps in my answer.

Comment: Okay, I never used JS before so I will stick with your solution, I put this answer as a solution. Thanks