# Combining DT::datatable, DT::dataTableProxy and "SearchPanes" Extension in R Shiny

Tags: r, filter, shiny, proxy, dt

It appears that `DT::dataTableProxy` is not possible with `SearchPanes` extension because:

- SearchPanes requires `Select` extension.
- `Select` extension requires `DT::renderDT(server = FALSE)` option.
- `DT::dataTableProxy` does not work on the client side and throws DT error.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    shiny::selectInput("rows", label = "Rows", choices = 1:nrow(mtcars)),
    shiny::actionButton("new", label = "New Data")
  ),
  dashboardBody(DT::dataTableOutput("cars"))
)

server <- function(input, output) { 
  rows <- reactive({ input$rows })
  output$cars <- DT::renderDataTable(server = FALSE, {
    expr = DT::datatable(
      data = mtcars |> head(rows()) 
      #,
      #extensions = c("SearchPanes", "Select", "Buttons"),
      #options = list(
      #  dom = "Btip",
      #  buttons = list("searchPanes")
      #)
    )

  })
  
  dtProxy <- DT::dataTableProxy("cars")
  
  observeEvent(input$new, label = "Observe button proxy update", {
    doubledata <- bind_rows(mtcars, mtcars)
    DT::replaceData(proxy = dtProxy, 
                    data = doubledata,
                    resetPaging = FALSE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Try this code using server = FALSE, click `New Data`, you will receive DT Warning:
`DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1`

Remove `server = FALSE` and proxy runs.

Remove the commented section, and search panes appear, but with no actual filters represented, and message stating that if we `really want to use select extension then set select = 'none'`.

Here are some reference materials:
[RStudio DT Extensions](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html)
[Matt Herman Tutorial](https://mattherman.info/blog/dt_searchpanes/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was use only the `DT::datatableProxy` feature, then use a custom button for the search panes. Custom button was found here [How to add custom button in R Shiny datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53600956/how-to-add-custom-button-in-r-shiny-datatable). This required making a new reactive which was invalidated by the first, and checking if the inputs had any new values. Then the proxy received the filtered data.

Maybe someday they will add support for search panes.

[Add server-side support for SearchPanes extension #877](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/877)