# How can I use the searchPanes extension and server-side processing in my R Shiny app?

Tags: shiny, datatables, dt

I've been able to create a working Shiny app with the datatables searchPanes extension. The problem is that my table is huge, which makes searchPanes go too slow; plus I have the cascadePanes option turned on, which slows down my table row filtering even more. Currently the data processing is done on the client side but I have read that it is more efficient on the server side, therefore I would like to change the configuration of my app to work on the server side.

This [link](https://datatables.net/extensions/searchpanes/serverside) on the datatables website explains how to configure searchPanes with server processing, but I don't know how to apply this information to my shiny application.

I attach a minimal example of my application with the iris data:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      iris,
      class = 'white-space: nowrap cell-border',
      extensions = c("SearchPanes", "Select", "Buttons", "Scroller"),
      selection = "none", rownames = F, filter = "none", 
      options = list(
        select = "multiple",
        scrollY = "497px", scrollCollapse = TRUE, searching = TRUE,
        scrollX = FALSE, autoWidth = FALSE,
        info = TRUE,
        paging = TRUE,
        dom = "Brtip",
        buttons = list(
          # searchPanes button
          list(
            extend="searchPanes",
            config = list(cascadePanes = T,combiner="and")
          ),
          # clear filters button
          list(
            extend="searchPanes",
            text="clear filters",
            action=JS(
              "function(e, table, node, config){",
              "   table.searchPanes.clearSelections();",
              "}"
            )
          ),
          # select all rows
          list(
            extend='selectAll',
            className='selectAll',
            text="select all",
            action = JS(
              "function(e, table, node, config) {",
              "  table.rows({ search: 'applied'}).deselect();",
              "  table.rows({ search: 'applied'}).select();",
              "}"
            )
            
          ),
          # deselect all rows
          "selectNone",
          # page length button
          "pageLength"
        ),
        language = list(
          # show number of active filters in button text
          searchPanes = list(collapse = paste("Filter rows: ",'Filters Selected - %d'))
        )
      )
    )
  },server = F)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75291215/combining-dtdatatable-dtdatatableproxy-and-searchpanes-extension-in-r-shi#new-answer) where the user Kraggle uses the function dataTableProxy() from the DT package, but I don't know how to capture the button input from searchpanes since I have defined it inside a custom button.

Comment: Just a note: "_it is more efficient on the server side_" - Yes, but in case it's not clear, this means you need to implement all your paging, searching and filtering logic yourself (in your code or using a library for this). When you use `serverSide: true`, DataTables no longer provides any of this functionality for you.

Comment: Any tips to improve performance on the client side? In my application I have activated the pagination and deferender options, but searchpanes still reacts quite slow (1-5 seconds to load the new available options). The table I'm working with has approximately 1250 rows and 9 columns. I would like to continue using searchpanes, as it is very powerful and versatile.